# Select data from MySQL database and put in R dataframe

Tags: sql, r, rmysql

I can access a MySQL database and store output to an R dataframe using the following script where **sam_pn = walker**

```
con <- dbConnect(MySQL(),
                 user = user,
                 password = password,
                 host = host,
                 dbname = dbname)

df = dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT *
                            FROM sam AS s
                            JOIN che AS c ON c.che_label = s.sam_label1
                            WHERE sam_pn =  'walker'")
```

But what i would like to do is store '**walker**' as an R value **pn** and then use  pn value in the sql query like below so i can vary the pn value.... but it does not work. The syntax is not right. Note **sam** and **che** are tables in the database

```
pn = 'walker'
df = dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT *
                            FROM sam AS s
                            JOIN che AS c ON c.che_label = s.sam_label1
                            WHERE sam_pn =  'pn'")
```

Comment: "Never" inject data into a query string, use bound parameters (or `glue::glue_sql`, though I generally recommend binding over glue). See https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/

Comment: Thanks for the link. I found the solution there. See below,

Answer (score 1):

```
pn = 'walker'
df = dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT *
                            FROM sam AS s
                            JOIN che AS c ON c.che_label = s.sam_label1
                            WHERE sam_pn =  ?",
      params = list(pn))
```

Comment: Thanks for the code onyambu but this did not work. This is what I 
eventually did.  

``` pn = 'walker' 

data = dbGetQuery(con, paste0("SELECT *
                            FROM sam AS s
                            JOIN che AS c ON c.che_label = s.sam_label1
                            WHERE sam_pn =  '", pn ,"'"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked in the end

```
pn = 'walker' 

data = dbGetQuery(con, paste0("SELECT *
                            FROM sam AS s
                            JOIN che AS c ON c.che_label = s.sam_label1
                            WHERE sam_pn =  '", pn ,"'"))
```

Comment: Ummm, I think you misunderstood both my comment and the link. Injecting data like this into your query is _really bad practice_, for several reasons. I strongly suggest you look harder at @onyambu's answer and confirm that it works for you. If you can come back rationale why this must be the only answer and onyambu's clearly does not work, then I'll remove my downvote, otherwise I'll assert-by-vote that this way is not canonical, not good practice, and can lead to problems in performance if not other issues.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks, @r2evans . I'll take your advice and concede to those more experienced than me and retry onyambu's method on the weekend and let you know.

Comment: @r2evans . Tried again and it definitely does not work. I get the follwing error.. Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
  unused argument (params = list("walker"))

Comment: OK, I found the problem with why that doesn't work ... [`RMySQL`](https://github.com/r-dbi/RMySQL/tree/main/R) hasn't had any significant code updates in (for the most part) 7 years, before `params=` become part of `DBI`-spec. Because of the age of `RMySQL`, I really suggest you install the MySQL odbc driver (https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/) and switch from `RMySQL` package to the `odbc` package.